# Can we use ''suffer'' in passive form?

Tags: word-usage, passive-voice

Can we use 'suffer' in passive form?
For example:

> Our skin can be suffered from spots .

Answer (score 4):

In one of its archaic meanings, "to allow", yes, you can:

> The physician was suffered to enter the queen's privy chamber.

But in its current *intransitive* sense of "to feel pain" or "to be afflicted with the symptoms of {some malady}"  it cannot be used in a passive construction (at least not in my dialect of American English).

P.S. Though it is fairly common to hear "damage" or "loss" **was suffered by**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it:

> The sunburn was suffered by Jim.